# can we change standard field title(text) into picklist on contact object

Tags: standard-field

Title is standard field on contact object. my requirement is i want to change data type Text into Picklist for Title field.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You've been a member here long enough you should know this question needs more detail. Please take a moment to (re-)visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

As Standard Fields cannot be changed you can create a Custom picklist field and Replace it with Standard field(Title) in all page layouts.